# Printing from Custom Layers in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am currently working on implementing AlexNet in Keras. Recently, I came across one implementation on this [repo](https://github.com/dandxy89/ImageModels) which is  a quite clean implementation of the AlexNet architecture. But I feel that there is some bug in the available code on this [line](https://github.com/dandxy89/ImageModels/blob/master/KerasLayers/Custom_layers.py#L20). If somehow I get to know a way to print the dimensions of the variables then I will be able to understand and resolve the bug. I tried `print` function and writing to a file but none of them seem to be working. Does anyone know what can we do to get something printed from such `custom layers` in Keras library?

Comment: Have you tried `model.summary()` function?

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So can I form the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `model.summary()' function. It prints a full information about your layers dimensions.